# Get file from Lightning input type file

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, upload, spring17

With the Spring 17 release one of the new change on the markup is the introduction of the type file to the lightning:input, however I can't seem to get the file back, only a fakepath with the name of the file.

I've tried

```
<lightning:input aura:id="fileSelector" type="File" label="Upload file"/>

component.find('fileSelector').get('v.files'));
```

Is there a way to get the file without using a standard input ?

Answer (score 6):

lightning:input is still beta, and has quite a few problems. It doesn't even currently have a [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) files attribute at the moment. As far as I'm aware, you still need to use a native input element of type "file".

Comment: But I'm using an org in Spring 17  and the documentation doesn't list it as beta anymore (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm)

Now I'm not allowed to push standard input anymore (via Illuminated cloud).

Comment: @NordineHammache Notice the Safe Harbor notes at the top. They're anticipating it'll be available for Spring 17, but it's probably not fully functional. Even if you *can* use it as described in those notes, you'll probably have to use `component.find("myInputField").getElement().datatransfer.files` instead of the simpler `component.find("myInputField").get("v.files")` you were anticipating.

Comment: Tried it but datatransfer comes back as undefined

Comment: I tried to but it does not work:

`component.find('fileInput').getElement().datatransfer.files`

Where datatransfer is undefined.

Comment: @SimonPlacentino I'll experiment and get back to you. I'm personally interested in knowing if we can.

Comment: @sfdcfox any news about ? A `find().getElement()` on a lightning input type file returns a div so I still need to do `childNodes[1].childNodes[0].files[0]`

Comment: Could I ask - does this component eliminate the need to encode files to string for form submission, or is this just an LDS-styled `<input type="file">` element? @SimonPlacentino @sfdcfox

Comment: It's just a styled one for the moment, hopefully that will change in the future

Comment: Hi guys, any news about `component.find('fileSelector').get('v.files'));`?

Comment: Still no workaround ?

Comment: If you are using onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }" on the lightning:input component, you can get the list of files by using the following command: event.target.files

Comment: @GoldenAxe Thanks for the update. I myself have noticed that this is available in Summer '17, but it didn't appear to work as of Spring '17 when this answer was written.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to use lightning:input as file selector, if you set an attribute in the component to store the files.

```
    <aura:attribute name="FileList" type="Object"/>
<lightning:input aura:id="file-input" type="file" files="{!v.FileList}" label="Files" 
                 name="file" multiple="true" onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }"/>
```

You can then access the files with component.get("v.FileList");

With LockerService off, the REST API is available to upload files, but I haven't figured out how to get the files uploaded to the cloud with LockerService activated yet.

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell, is this post meant to be an answer or a new question?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }" on the lightning:input component, you can get the list of files by using the following command: event.getSource().get("v.files"), according to the docs.

I have tried it myself (on v40) and it is working.

**..helper.js:**

```
handleFilesChange : function(component, event)
{
    var uploadFile = event.getSource().get("v.files")[0];
}
```