# How do i empty the value in lightning without violating DOM Modification

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, security-review, dom

Component

```
<input onchange="{! c.readCSV}" accept=".csv" type="file" id="file-upload"  aura:id="file-upload"/>
```

Controller

```
readCSV : function(component, event, helper){
var file = component.find("file-upload").getElement().files[0];//Violation in security review
/* all file processing takes place */

//now i need to empty the file (on change event wont be fired if the same file is uploaded twice)

component.find("file-upload").getElement().value = ""; //Violation in security review

}
```

The above code works well but violates DOM Modification . is ther any way to empty the values?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/169242/550 It uses a lightning:input + an attribute to set the filelist

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating the DOM the framework manages for you, then it should happen in the Renderer.

Inorder to access **input[type=file]** element in **Renderer** you need to do below:

1) Have an aura:attribute of type boolean, which will be set when onchange of the **input[type=file]** element is fired

2) Once the aura:attribute is set to `true`(i.e changed), rerender of the component will be fired

3) In **rerender**, empty the **input[type=file]** element's value and make sure aura:attribute is set to `false` at end

With that said, I'm not sure why retrieving the file content by accessing the Input File element is being flag by the Security Review Team, since there's no DOM Manipulation is done. Please reach out to the Partner Community, the Security Team members over there might help you out on this.

To access the file content, you can do in the Renderer as well. Check the below sample code:

**myApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="isFileChanged" type="Boolean" default="false" access="private"/>    
    <input onchange="{!c.readFile}" accept=".csv" type="file" id="file-upload"  aura:id="file-upload"/>

</aura:application>
```

**controller**

```
({
    readFile : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isFileChanged" , true);
    }
})
```

**Renderer**

```
({
    // Your renderer method overrides go here
    rerender : function(component, helper) {
        this.superRerender();
        console.log('rerender called')
        if(component.get("v.isFileChanged")) {
            var fileEle = component.find("file-upload").getElement();
            var file = fileEle.files[0];

            /*
             * call helper logic to process file
             * 
             */

            fileEle.value = "";
            component.set("v.isFileChanged" , false);
        }
    }
})
```

NOTE : Since **rerender** is fired multiple times in the LC's lifecycle be cautious while using it.